# Getting error when using GitHub Actions to push the nupkg to my GitHub packages

Tags: github, nuget-package, github-actions, manage-nuget-packages

**Question:**

Im getting a "Specified source 'github' is invalid" error when trying to build and push a NuGet package to GitHub nuget Packages.

Does anyone know why? or, what the source should be, I cant see anything in the GitHub documentation about this value, or even the end url that will host my packages(im hoping it will just show in the packages tab when one is created)

**Question Details:**

I have just seen that you GitHub have Actions now, so you can get your code to build/test when changes are merged.

I have also seen that you can now also pubish a NuGet package and host it within GitHub too.

Looking at the screenshot below, it seems it should be quite easy to do

[image]

It took me a while to realize i needed to create an Action to put this code into... so here is my action code (yml)

[image]

now, this action runs when i commit, and it all passes until the last line, for pushing to github.  I get an error ***"The specified source 'github' is invalid. Please provide a valid source***"

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add GitHub as a resource in your Nuget configuration

you can use the following command line:

> dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password ${{
> secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github
> "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OWNER/index.json"

where GITHUB_TOKEN could be a PAT token as well,
check more information in the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages).

That command line will append the source to your config file

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because `github` is not defined in the `--source "github"` command.
I admit the documentation (https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry) isn't very clear.
In order to *publish* to the same github nuget repository do something like the following in your yaml:

```
      - run: dotnet nuget add source --username shiraze --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/shiraze-company/index.json"
      - run: dotnet nuget push "MyPackage.1.1.0.nupkg" --source "github"
```

My username is `shiraze`, so replace that with yours. I'm publishing to a private github nuget repository, so replace `shiraze-company` either with the organisation you wish to publish to, or your username (to publish to your own profile).

This route *doesn't* require you to create a Personal Access Token. You will need a PAT, though, when *restoring* private nuget repositories - as documented on the above page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is your `NuGet.Config`? I would imagine given the error message that there is no source in it named `github`. You need to publish to a source that actually exists in your configuration, otherwise how does `nuget` know where to publish to?

An example `NuGet.Config` file might look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="SomeOtherSource" value="https://some.source.maybe.jfrog.com/nuget/nuget-local" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

If you don't have a source with `key="github"`, your command will fail.

You can find more information on GitHub Packages w/NuGet [here](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages)